# Python script stops after I run a function

Tags: python

I recently started using python and wanted to use it in a project and so far I've gotten:

```
def jlogin():
    botcheckstatus = input("Have you completed the \"Are You Human\" check yet? (Y): ")
    if botcheckstatus == "Y" or botcheckstatus == "y":
        temp = chrome.find_element_by_id("userid")
        temp.send_keys(username)
        temp.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(1)
        temp = chrome.find_element_by_id("pass")
        temp.send_keys(password)
        temp.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
 
jlogin()
print("wont work")
```

What I dont understand is why pyhton wont run the print command at the end when it runs I assume that I am not using the def fuction right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "def function". `def` is short for _define_; a **function** is its own thing. You're _defining_ a _function_.

Comment: How are you running the script? Does it prompt "Have you completed ..."? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Also it seems you haven't debugged this script by stepping though it line-by-line. Debugging your own code is an essential skill that all programmers need to learn on day 1; if you have to rely on internet strangers to do it for you you're doing yourself and everyone a massive disservice. PyCharm is free and has an excellent debugger; here is how to use it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: @jarmod I have ran the script on a raspberry pi 4 in thorny and it did prompt me in which I did then reply and it continued through the script, the only thing it doesn’t do is execute the print line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the last print didn't work is because jlogin() has an error.

I fixed your coding a little bit.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def jlogin():
    username = "id"
    password = "pw"
    botcheckstatus = input("Have you completed the \"Are You Human\" check yet? (Y): ")
    if botcheckstatus == "Y" or botcheckstatus == "y":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver") #chromedriver pathway
        chrome = driver.get("https://example.com")
        temp = chrome.find_element_by_id("userid")
        temp.send_keys(username)
        temp.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)
        temp = chrome.find_element_by_id("pass")
        temp.send_keys(password)
        temp.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        
jlogin()
print("wont work")
```

Isn't it because you forgot to import it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

I hope it's the answer you want. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fix this, but the reason those imports and variables were not in the script is because that was only a small section of the script and it had sensitive info in the rest of it.

Comment: I see. Then there seems to be nothing wrong except adding time. to sleep(1).